# PHP Sessions: Session Cookies sent by subsequents requests dissappear ($_COOKIE['sessionName'] empty)

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am using a database-based implementation of PHP's `SessionHandlerInterface`.
The implementation works perfectly on my local installation, but i have problems with the session cookies on my providers webspace:

Subsequent client-to-server requests (fetching some css and js files) sending a cookie with the session ID the first (login-)request received (as shown in the developer tools of chrome and firefox) seem to arrive without any session cookie information at the server - `COOKIE['sessionName']` is not set.

Therefore these resources can't be loaded properly, because they are only available, when the user is logged in - what he should be after the first login-request.

These are the ini-settings i use:

```
ini_set('session.auto_start', 0);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.entropy_length', '256');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440;
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 10);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', '5');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha256');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');
```

what also is done prior calling `session_start()` is:

```
session_name('sid');
session_set_save_handler($this, true);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']), true);
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

What could be the causes of such a problem - how can a session cookie dissapear on its way from the client to the server?

Comment: you should set your ini file and for test read it back. many providers dont allow changes in server settings.

Comment: I check every ini_set return value and throw an exception if any returned false. PHP doc. says `Returns the old value on success, FALSE on failure.` But I'll give it a try.

Comment: I checked the ini settings. All return via `ini_get()` the value I set.